# Elementor contact form attach file

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I can not change style for attach file field can I change it with custom css and how

```
#form-field-box3{
  background-color: #F3F3F3;
  color: red;
  padding: 13px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

input#file-upload-button {
    background-color: red;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 50px;`enter code here`
}
```

They are not working

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following and working for me

```
/* For Fields */
selector .elementor-field-group:not(.elementor-field-type-upload) .elementor-field:not(.elementor-select-wrapper):focus, selector .elementor-field-group .elementor-select-wrapper select:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
    border-bottom-color: #4632da;
}
selector .elementor-field-textual {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
/* Making checkbox and radio button invisible */
selector input[type="checkbox"], selector input[type="radio"] {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
}
/* For Radio button */
.elementor-field-group-mt_radio > div label:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    border-radius: 100%;
    vertical-align: -3px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    padding: 0.13em;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-clip: content-box;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.elementor-field-group-mt_radio > div label {
    margin-right: 1em;
}
.elementor-field-group-mt_radio > div input:hover + label:before {
    border-color: #4632da;
}
.elementor-field-group-mt_radio > div input:checked + label:before {
    background-color: #4632da;
    border-color: #4632da;
}
/* For Checkbox */
.elementor-field-group-mt_checkbox > div label:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    vertical-align: -3px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    padding: 0.12em;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-clip: content-box;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.elementor-field-group-mt_checkbox > div label {
    margin-right: 1em;
    position: relative;
}
.elementor-field-group-mt_checkbox > div label:after {
    border-right: 2px solid #fff;
    border-top: 2px solid #fff;
    content: "";
    height: 11px;
    left: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 11px;
    transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(135deg);
    transform-origin: left top;
    width: 6px;
    display: none;
}
.elementor-field-group-mt_checkbox > div input:hover + label:before {
    border-color: #4632da;
}
.elementor-field-group-mt_checkbox > div input:checked + label:before {
    border-color: #4632da;
    background: #4632da;
}
.elementor-field-group-mt_checkbox > div input:checked + label:after {
    -moz-animation: check 0.8s ease 0s running;
    -webkit-animation: check 0.8s ease 0s running;
    animation: check 0.8s ease 0s running;
    display: block;
    width: 6px;
    height: 11px;
    border-color: #fff;
}
@keyframes check {
 0% {
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
}
 25% {
 height: 0;
 width: 6px;
}
 50% {
 height: 11px;
 width: 6px;
}
}
```

check it out and let me know

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I will let you know